# Does Entity Framework Core DbContext SaveChanges call DetectChanges implicitly when it throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

As a scenario, an entity has a xmin concurrency check which is equivalent of `RowVersion` column in PostgreSQL database. While updating this entity, there is a loop like below to force update operation as a last in wins strategy.

```
var entities = entityListContainsEntitiesModifiedByUser;
using var context = new ExampleDbContext();

while(true) 
{
    try
    {
        var entitiesWillBeUpdated = context.Set<TEntity>().Where(x => !entities.Contains(x)).ToList();
        context.UpdateRange(entitiesWillBeUpdated);
  
        // Some of entities have deleted since round before.
        // (This line will be mentioned later below)     
        context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        var revertEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Where(x => !entitiesWillBeUpdated.Contains(x.Entity)).ToList();
  
        foreach(var revert in reverEntities) 
        {
            revert.State == EntityState.Detach;
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        break;
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException e) 
    {
        var entry = e.Entries.Single();
        var dbval = await entry.GetDatabaseValues(); 

        if (dbval == null) 
        {
            // Updating entry has been deleted so it cant be modified.  Ignore it.
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
            continue;
        }

        // Updating entry has been concurrently updated by someone else so change the old version to the new one
        var pxmin = entry.Property("xmin")!;
        pxmin.CurrentValue =  dbval.GetValue<uint>("xmin");
        pxmin.OriginalValue =  dbval.GetValue<uint>("xmin");
    }
}
```

If we go step by step, assume that user modified 1000 entities and we want to update these. In try  block all 1000 entities are tracked and set as modified. There is 0 revertEntities at this point because this is first round so no tracked entities fetched from database before. Then, `SaveChanges` is called. While EF Core updating these entities, there is 1 entity modified inside that 1000 entities concurrently by other users.

So a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is caught. In the catch block new xmin version of this 1 entity is set. Before trying again to update all 1000 records, there is some time and assume in this time, 300 records of the 1000 are deleted. In next round, entitiesWillBeUpdated have 700 records and `ExampleDbContect` tracks 1000 entities which is loaded round before and 300 of them is deleted from database so revertEntities have 300 entities inside.

These 300 entities are set as detached and `SaveChanges` is called.

At this point 1 of 700 entities is modified again by another user. In next round, this 1 modified entity's xmin version is updated.

The question is:

At this point, will `revertEntities` have 300 detached entities again or are they cleared from `ExampleDbContext` and be untracked because of `SaveChanges` call made a round before so will it have 0 entities inside?

I know SaveChanges implicitly calls `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` but what if a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown?

I know that when this exception is thrown tracked entity values in memory whose state are set modified is not changed but if there is no exception, this entity values have new values same with theirs record in database updated. Is same thing is true for detached entities?

Normally if no error is thrown all of them were cleared from `ExampleDbContext` and not be tracked. So in last situation, are detached entities cleared or they still exist locally? Do I need to call `DetectChanges()` manually like the comment line in the code?

Comment: *force update operation as a last in wins* - if you want that, why don't you just not have a concurrency token?

Comment: Because some columns of the entitiy is not updated as a last in wins. The update operation in this example is a representative sample. In real one some part of columns is updated and no need to control concurrency but In another kind of update operation out of scope, some of the columns are need to be concurrent and the update operation need to be applied when some conditions are met. So there is 2 different update operation and in one of them there is a need to control concurrency. I tried to find ignore concurrency control when it is not needed but i couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the case in another project and I see that, while detaching a tracked entry and AutoDetectChanges is enabled (by default it is enabled), entries are deleted from Entries list of ChangeTracker after `Entry.State = EntryState.Detached` line immediately. So, no need to wait for SaveChanges or DetectChanges call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).